# Networkdays based on conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 5 columns with Date inputs. Col. 1 always has a date; Columns 2-5, may have dates depending on events that take place. Basically I have a tracker of when a request is received, when acknowledgement of request is sent, and when the request is complete. I am trying to calculate turnaround time in order to create a dashboard.

A KPI is how fast I am able to acknowledge a request or complete the request. As such I need a formula that will calculate the workdays between the date received and those two other milestones. Two things can happen; I acknowledge a request, in which case there in an input in Col. B, or I can close a case, in which case, there is no input in Col. B, but there is input in Col. C. Col. A always has an input.

I'm trying things such as:

`=IF(A2="","n/a",IF(NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2)<=2,"Y"))`

I just don't know how to connect that formula to:

`=IF(C2="","n/a",IF(NETWORKDAYS(A2,C2)<=2, "Y"))`

What I want is for the formula to check if there is a value in B2, if there is, do a calculation and stop then, if there is no value then move to C2, if there is a value, then calculate. If there are no values in B2 or C2, then respond with "n/a"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest your IFs with OR and AND

```
=IF(A2<>"",IF(OR(B2<>"",C2<>""),IF(NETWORKDAYS(A2,IF(B2<>"",B2,C2))>2,"Y","N/A"),"N/A"),"N/A")
```

[image]